# Lua implementation of *

Tags: lua

How can I implement vba-like symbol `*` in Lua?
I want to compare pattern like `"aabb*"` in strings `"aaabbb"` (false) or `"aabbds"` (true).

Comment: Do you need other vba-like special features: `?`, `#`, `[charlist]`, `[!charlist]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function string.like(text, pattern)
   pattern = "^"..pattern:gsub("*", "\0"):gsub("%p", "%%%0"):gsub("%z", ".-").."$"
   return text:find(pattern) and true or false
end
```

Usage is `local bool_result = str:like(pattern)`

```
local pattern = "aabb*"

print(("aaabbb"):like(pattern))   --> false
print(("aabbds"):like(pattern))   --> true
```

Comment: What, is’t Lua? Basically, Ruby syntax. 1st time seeing :)